# EXCEL: Lookup Table based on Inputs and Provide Corresponding Output Value based on BEST FIT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup-tables, best-fit

Am looking for help regarding the below Size Predictor for Apparels

I have a standardized table which has the Dress Sizes namely *S, M, L, XL, 2-XL, 3-XL* and the associated measurements of key body parameters which are mapped to the standard industry sizes. This is the size chart which is a standardized with many of the apparel manufacturers.

The idea is the user will provide in the input box the actual measurements of self. Based on the inputs, all the 3 inputs will be checked against the respective columns and will provide the output which size is the best fit for the user.

Important aspect is, each input parameter provided by the user must not be lesser than the value in the corresponding columns in the table as this will result in the apparel being too tight in various body positions. The apparel should have a slack fit or perfect fit in all the various body positions. The result should give the corresponding sizes where all the 3 inputs less than or equal to the corresponding values in the the size table to ensure a loose or perfect fit.

[image]

E.g.  As in the example given below bust size of 112 which is the input, *Small* will not be correct since 112 is higher than 109, but size *Medium* will fit.
 But if I choose *Medium* then Waist size of 101 is higher than size of 96 in *Medium* which means *Medium* will be a tight fit in the waist so I have to look for *Large* where 101 is lesser than 102 and will have a slack fit of 1 cm. But if I consider the Hip size input of 128 against *Medium* which is a slack fit in Bust and Waist, in Hip 128 is higher than 127, which means though Bust and Waist are a slack fit in *Medium* size the dress might not still fit me at Hip so I have to select *X-Large*.

So at X*-Large* the Bust will have a slack of 12cm, Waist a slack of 6cm and Hip a slack of 4cm. So the output for me should be suggesting a size *X-Large* for the dimensions I input.

So I need a formula in the output box where the input is being progressively checked in the table to show the closet slack fit of dress size for the dimensions of the body.

Requesting Experts to help here please

[Example of the Size Chart, Input and Output Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbbXF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find all three fits with `match()` then choose the largest:
First reverse the sorting of your table, so it goes from 2XL to Small, instead of Small to 2XL.  Now use:

`=index(a2:a7,  min(match(g2, b2:b7,-1),match(g3, c2:c7,-1),match(g4, d2:d7,-1)))`

**How it works:**

Find the "Bust" match like this:
`=match(g2, b2:b7,-1)`   *(Note:  I am assuming that "Size" is cell A1 in your picture.")*

By default `match` matches the first row with a value less than or equal to your lookup.  You want the last row where it is greater than or equal to your input.  We can't do a "last row" match, so reverse the table and use the `, -1` flag to find the first row with a value greater than or equal to your lookup.

Then do this for all three, and wrap in a min:

`=min(match(g2, b2:b7,-1),match(g3, c2:c7,-1),match(g4, d2:d7,-1))`

Then wrap `index()` around them to get the name of the size that controlled..

`=index(a2:a7,  min(match(g2, b2:b7,-1),match(g3, c2:c7,-1),match(g4, d2:d7,-1)))`

Comment: Hi thanks for the help here. I tried this. The result came as Large. But the Result should come as X-Large. I will tell why. The Match function used finds the relatively closer value to the input in the table. So for 128 Hip size the realtively Closer value is 127 and taking a Max function it gives Large, but if you see 128 is the size of the user and the dress will be 127 cm. It will not fit him. The predictor should suggest X-Large as 132 of Hip Size is higher than 128. There should be check for each parameter whether the size selected for the corresponding input is greater than the input

Comment: See edit.  You can use `Data --> Sort` to reverse your table easily.

Comment: Having reversed the table, now you will need to find the `min` value, instead of the `max`.

Comment: Yes this worked. Am trying all combinations. This is working. Let me put all permutations combinations and try. Thanks Adam

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all permutations and this is working. Adam Thank you very much. Appreciate the quick response.

Am just going to add a value add to my users who use my Size Predictor and tell them not only which Size is suitable for them but am going to tell them how much allowance they have in each body part against their measurement and whether they will have a Slack Fit, Perfect Fit or Tight Fit

So after get the Output which is the Size now we have to compare each value of the Output Row. Since the output values are higher than the input we should do a subtraction and show how much allowance is there. If there is a positive allowance the other column should read as Slack Fit, If Zero allowance the other column should read as PErfect fit and If Negative it should read as Tight Fit (Ideally Tight Fit should not come because we are looking for all dimensions to fit)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r1Tl.jpg)

Comment: You're welcome!  Stack exchange is a little different from a forum.  If my post was helpful, you should vote it up (click the triangle above the number on the left side of my post.  If it fully answered my question, you should come back in a day or two and mark it answered (the check mark below the number.  If you have a follow up question, you should ask a brand new question that refers back to this one.    When you do so, show what you have tried.  The solution to Q2 is likely going to involve some similar functions as the solution to Q1.  Try it out!  Use `if()`, `match()`, and `index()`

Comment: Because this isn't really an answer to your original question, it is likely to be deleted pretty quickly.

Comment: Thank you. Understood how Stack works. Let me try as suggested

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I tried to you the similar Index Match and then applied If and am getting the result as needed. This is awesome. Am trying to apply this in my webportal for Size Chooser by customer. Thanks Adam. I will come back in 2 days to provide the feedback that this answered my question fully